# Missing log output from static logger class field

Tags: jenkins, logging, junit, log4j, log4j2

When executing JUnit tests in a Maven build on Jenkins some logs are not being written to the console.

```
class Foo {
    static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo.class);

    static Logger log() {
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foo.class);
    }

    void baz() {
        log.error("error 1")
        log().error("error 2")
    }
}
```

Method `baz` is called from my JUnit test and `error 2` is logged when executing the build on Jenkins, but `error 1` is missing. Locally I cannot reproduce the problem. Executing the same Maven build on my machine I see the output of both logging statements.

I run the same Java version on Jenkins and locally:

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.16.1+1 (build 11.0.16.1+1)
```

Any pointers what could be causing this or how I could further drill down into the problem for finding the root cause?

**Update:** I can see that the `Logger` instance from the first logging statement is a different one than the one from the second logging statement.

Comment: Does this also happen if you use the Log4j2 API directly instead of SLF4j? What versions of the libraries are you using?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz, same problem when using log4j directly and acquiring the logger via `LogManager.getLogger`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out some other tests in our suite ends up calling `LogManager.shutdown` at some point. This causes the static final logger reference to become stale. Apparently this only started showing up after some other unrelated changes caused the order of test execution to change so the shutdown of the logging system would happen *before* the relevant logger is being used in another test.